# Video sphere does not work

Tags: html, aframe

Video sphere does not work. It's showing white screen. Video does not play.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello, WebVR! - A-Frame</title>
<meta name="description" content="Hello, WebVR! - A-Frame">
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a-scene>
  <a-assets>
    <video id="video" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/eb8b5b90-b564-46cc-a9bd-abd27ce76783%2Fvideo.mp4?1524149938496" autoplay="true" 
           loop="true" crossorigin="anonymous" playsinline webkit-playsinline></video>
  </a-assets>
  <a-videosphere id="video-screen" src="#video"></a-videosphere>
</a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

It showing this error: Error: WebGL warning: drawArrays: Active texture 0 for target 0x0de1 is 'incomplete', and will be rendered as RGBA(0,0,0,1), as per the GLES 2.0.24 $3.8.2: The dimensions of `level_base` are not all positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in aframe v0.8.0: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3444

The fix was done in v0.8.2: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/commit/5ead860379ebe61d2ef1f2acbe2eed5537ccc682

So if you change your script src to "https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.2/aframe.min.js", it shall work.